# Can someone help me understand the positioning of the quotation marks in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, string-concatenation

I am new to javascript and was hoping someone might be able to explain to me why certain quotes are placed where they are. I understand in the code below, where I left comments, that it is 3 strings being combined into one however I do not understand why the quotes are placed where they are. I'm sure the answer is obvious but I am having trouble wrapping my head around it. As I under stand it the 3 parts are tag_opening + anchor_count + tag_closing. Just confused on the single ' ' quotes and why they are where they are. Thank you in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("document").ready(function() {    
        buildBookmarks('h3', 'header'); 
    }); 

    function buildBookmarks(strWhichTag, sBookMarkNode) {

        var cAnchorCount = 0;
        var oList = $("<ul id='bookmarksList'>");

        $("div:not([id=header])" + strWhichTag).each(function() {
            //I'm confused on the quotation placement and why it cannot look like this: 
            //"<li><a href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++' + ">" -OR- 
            //"<a name='bookmark" + cAnchorCount + >' + "</a>"
            $(this).html("<a name='bookmark" + cAnchorCount + "'></a>" + $(this).html());
            oList.append($("<li><a href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</a></li>"));
        });
        $("#" + sBookMarkNode).append(oList);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because to create valid markup, the attribute values need to be wrapped, be it in single quotes or double quotes. Fortunately, the use of which type doesn't matter, as long as you're consistent within a given string (though at least try to use the same approach in all your code).

As an example, this line:

```
$("<li><a href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</a></li>")
```

Would generate this markup:

```
<li><a href='#bookmarkSomeAnchorCount'>Some Text</a></li>
```

And the same would be true if you reverse the use of quotes. This new line:

```
$('<li><a href="#bookmark' + cAnchorCount++ + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a></li>')
```

Would generate this markup:

```
<li><a href="#bookmarkSomeAnchorCount">Some Text</a></li>
```

In essence, one quote type is being used to delineate string literals while the other is a character you want to include within the resulting string because the resulting markup requires it to be valid.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing pretty much the same thing. Gave you an upvote.

Comment: If you could clarify for me why does the single quoted part need to be in quotes at all? '#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + "'

Comment: The code actually works without quotes around that part: $("<li><a href=#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++ + ">" + $(this).text() + "</a></li>") Makes more sense to me this way

Comment: It certainly may "work" in your browser if the HREF attribute value is not wrapped in a quote (single or double) in the resulting markup, but it's not syntactically correct. You also run the risk that any of a number of characters (spaces, quotes themselves, an equals sign, etc) will result in mal-formed attribute values.

Comment: Thank you! I was failing to understand that the single quotation ' was actually part of the string itself! I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple. " and ' are exactly the same in JavaScript and you can have a string with one of them, if its quoted with the other.

Generally HTML properties use ". So to have a template HMTL string with a lot of ", its easier to quote the JavaScript string with '.

For this reason, I have seen JS projects use ' alone consistently.